# Dependencies issue while running apache nutch webservice

Tags: nutch

While creating the configuration of nutch in deploy mode using the config/create endpoint it is throwing NoSuchMethodError.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.forType(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.base.ProviderBase.readFrom(ProviderBase.java:803)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBodyReader(JAXRSUtils.java:1379)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.readFromMessageBody(JAXRSUtils.java:1330)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameter(JAXRSUtils.java:856)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.processParameters(JAXRSUtils.java:815)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:215)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.doService(JettyHTTPDestination.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPHandler.handle(JettyHTTPHandler.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    19/03/22 01:46:25 WARN thread.QueuedThreadPool:
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine$1.handle(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response.sendError(Response.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handleException(HttpChannel.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$HttpChannelOverHttp.handleException(HttpConnection.java:621)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:258)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This method belongs to jackson-databind-2.9.5.jar when I checked into apache-nutch-1.15.job the same version jar exists in it.